# Android pass reference to activity

Tags: android, android-activity, reference

Currently I have the following code:

```
public class GameMenu extends Activity{
    //some code
    public void showOptions(View view){
        if(view.equals(R.id.optionsButton){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, OptionsMenu.class);
            intent.putExtra("FACADE",this.gameFacade);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

**OptionsMenu**

```
public class OptionsMenu extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_options_controller);
            Intent calledFromIntend = getIntent();
            this.facade = (Facade) calledFromIntend.getSerializableExtra("facade");
    }
//some more code
}
```

Is it possible that the facade is the same in class GameMenu and OptionsMenu?
Because now it's a copy, so if the user checks option x in OptionsMenu, it isn't known in GameMenu.

Comment: why dont you just use a sharedPreference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not the same because it gets deserialized from the one you pass in the Intent. You can use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity` in the GameMenu to get a result back from OptionsMenu. See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html for more info.